# Pandas _period_range function not working when extracted date from data frame

Tags: python, pandas, date-range

I need to access the date range from the data frame and specify in period_range()
Issue:  Even though I am passing a string as argument, it doesn't work. Kindly suggest where am I going wrong.

[Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VRuQM.png)

Below mentioning the code I tried:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime
datas=[['project1','26-06-2021','02-07-2021']]
cols=['project','startdate','enddate']
data1=pd.DataFrame(data=datas,columns=cols)
print(data1.head())
str1 =pd.to_datetime(data1['startdate'][0]).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
str2 =pd.to_datetime(data1['enddate'][0]).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
range=pd.period_range(str1,str2,freq='M')
print(range)
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1HbUY.png)

PeriodIndex([], dtype='period[M]')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is `str1` is parsed like `February`, possible solution is add `dayfirst=True` parameter:

```
str1 =pd.to_datetime(data1['startdate'][0], dayfirst=True).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
str2 =pd.to_datetime(data1['enddate'][0], dayfirst=True).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
r=pd.period_range(str1,str2,freq='M')
print(r)
PeriodIndex(['2021-06', '2021-07'], dtype='period[M]', freq='M')
```

Comment: Yes when swapped it works.But the expected answer is   PeriodIndex(['2021-06', '2021-07']) as the input date range being[ 26-06-2021 ,02-07-2021]

Comment: @VIDYARENUKA - Can you check edited answer?

Comment: @VIDYARENUKA - pandas by default parse month names first, so parse `02-07-2021` like 7.February. So necessary specify first value is day, not month.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know ..Appreciate your help